# How to use QLPreviewController in the Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, quicklook

Is it possible to use the QLPreviewController in the Interface Builder? I am using storyboards and segues, and it would be lovely to also have a representation for the QLPreviewController.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked the same question several weeks ago. As far as I know there is no representation for the QuickLook Framework. But it shouldn't be too hard to get this done programmatically.

I suppose you have an UITableView. Then implement `QLPreviewControllerDataSource` into your header and the following two methods to your implementation:

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller;
- (id <QLPreviewItem>) previewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller previewItemAtIndex: (NSInteger) index;
```

Don't set a segue for the cells and leave the storyboard methods. Instead in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` create a new instance of a QLPreviewController and push it onto the stack of the navigation controller.

```
PreviewController* previewController = [[PreviewController alloc] init];
[previewController setDataSource:self];
[previewController setDelegate:self];
[previewController setCurrentPreviewItemIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:previewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: @northsea, this is how i've implemented mine for iPhone but I'm making a universal app, so for iPad i have a split view controller in the storyboard and i want the masterview to be the tableview and the detail view to be a subclassed QLPreviewContorller. Any thoughts? Much appreciated, Thanks